# how to fix scroll position of inner div based on parent div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> my design was in 2 columns
>   first column: width 50px for menu
>   second column: width remaining px

In second column
Based on parent div height: 15611px(this may vary on content length) inner div position top position should change negatively

> Second column:

```
<div class="column-wrapper" style="height:15611px;">
     <div class="homepage-column-left"  style="top:-5px"> 

          ----content------ images

     </div>
     <div class="homepage-column-right"  style="top:-5px"> 

          ----content------ images

     </div>
</div>
```

i expect that top position value should change into negative on scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top: -5px;` won't do anything unless the element also has `position: absolute;` and the parent element has `position: relative;`

I'd recommend css instead of inline, but here is what you need using inline styling...

```
<div class="column-wrapper" style="height: 15611px; position: relative;">
    <div class="homepage-column -left"  style="top:-5px; position: absolute;"> 
        ----content------ images
    </div>
    <div class="homepage-column -right"  style="top:-5px; position: absolute;"> 
        ----content------ images
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To position a child element "fixed" relative to a parent element, you can use position:absolute on the child element, and any position mode other than the default or static on your parent element.

For example:

```
<div class="column-wrapper" style="height: 15611px; position: relative;">
    <div class="homepage-column -left"  style="top:-5px; position: absolute;"> 
        ----content------ images
    </div>
    <div class="homepage-column -right"  style="top:-5px; position: absolute;"> 
        ----content------ images
    </div>
</div>
```